# Start another app from last activity

Tags: android

I need to start another app from my service, but I don't want to "restart" the other app from its main screen. I'd like to open it starting from the last activity the user saw. From my service I'm using:

```
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
        i.setPackage(lastPackage);
        startActivity(i);
```

but this code doesn't work. I need to use the "new task" flag because I'm in a service. How can I do?

Comment: You would need to manipulate the other app, otherwise you can't change its lifecycle behaviour or entry points. Can you do that?

Comment: No I can't, so the only thing I can do is to start it from the main, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you can start the app via `Intent` and it will come up in whatever state it is at that time. If it was in the background and Android didn't kill it yet, it will resume. Otherwise it will start the point defined by `Intent.ACTION_MAIN`. But you can't influence the app lifecycle...

Comment: No it doesn't work in that way. The app is always restarted from the main, I think because there is the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK but I can't remove it in this case